# SPARQL: Finding the relation that connects two entities from a list of possible relations

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

I have two sets of entities, `entities1` and `entities2` and I want to identify all relations that link the two together, from a specified set of relations.

This can be done by declaring the relation as a variable:

`?entities1 ?relations ?entities2`

However, this iterates over all possible relations, therefore making the query incredibly slow and inefficient.

This could also be done by declaring the relations needed using a OR operator:

`?entities1 (relation1 | relation2 | ... | relation_n) ?entities2`

This finds all of the cases where entities 1 and 2 are linked by one of our relations but the relation is not returned, therefore it's not known which relation was correct.

I need a method of finding the relations between each entity from a specified set of relations that can then be returned as a table with the headers (entity1, entity2, relation).

Any ideas?

Comment: `VALUES ?relation {:relation1 :relation2 ... :relation_n} ?entities1 ?relation ?entities2 .`

Comment: Worked a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

@UninformedUser kindly pointed out that a set of relations can be declared by using `VALUES` meaning that the desired effect can be achieved as follows:

`VALUES ?relation {:relation1 :relation2 ... :relation_n} ?entities1 ?relation ?entities2 .`

Thanks for your help!